# Cookies and multiple browser windows/tabs

Tags: jquery, html, cookies, jquery-cookie

I'm trying to share some information between browser windows/tabs, and I'm leery of HTML5 local storage because of browser support issues. Some googling lead me to believe cookies can be used for this, so I grabbed jquery.cookie and set up a simple test.

Two pages which write a cookie when loaded:

```
$.cookie("testValue", new Date().getTime());
```

and a button that displays the cookie value in an alert on each:

```
alert($.cookie("testValue"));
```

When testing, I see different values on each page, which would lead me to believe this just doesn't work, but I keep running across posts here and elsewhere where people seem to be recommending it, so I'm wondering if I'm just doing something wrong?

Comment: It sounds like you never try to read the cookie on a page before you override it with the current time. If so, why would the results be the same?

Comment: the test is, load page in tab 1, load page in tab 2. so the cookie should have the value set by tab 2. I see different values in tab 1 and tab 2 when I click the button. What I want is to see tab 2's value on both pages.

Comment: Then that's the problem. You *do* overwrite the cookie value before you try to read it back. *Load page 1. Set Cookie. Read cookie. Load page 2. **Set Cookie**. Read cookie.*

Comment: I don't think we're communicating well ;) I still see Page1's cookie value when I click the button on Page1. Similarly, Page2 shows me it's value. What I want is for both pages to have the newest (Page2's) value. So I WANT page2 to overwrite page1's cookie. This isn't happening.

Comment: Also, this is intentionally a client-side only affair. The cookie is NOT coming from the server.

Answer (score 2):

Cookies are only updated in the JavaScript environment when set by JS, or when the page loads.

localStorage was designed for this. IE8 supports it just fine, it's only the really old IE7 and below that don't. Although IE9 is Windows-Vista-and-7-only, IE8 is fine on XP so you should have no troubles asking your users who are still on archaic browsers to update.

(I can't say this enough, but IE really need an auto-updater like all other browsers...)

Comment: This is a corporate app, IE7 has to be supported. And what do you mean they are only updated when set by JS? Isn't that what I'm doing here?

Comment: I mean they're only updated in the current window by being set in that window. Other windows have to be reloaded to see the change. I'll add another answer with a solution you might be more interested in.

Comment: So a reload is required. That's where I thought I was going to wind up, just looking for confirmation.

Comment: See my other answer - I think it takes care of the problem quite well :)

Comment: @lamont You can reload an `iframe`.

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime()` is not defined. Use `Date()` instead.

`$.cookie("testValue", new Date().getTime());`

Anyway, it works for me. Here's a simple html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>demo</title>  
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js'></script>  
  <script type='text/javascript' src="https://raw.github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/master/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(window).load(function(){
        $("#get").click(function(){
            alert($.cookie("testValue"));
        });
        $("#set").click(function(){
            $.cookie("testValue", new Date().getTime());
        });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <a id="get" href="#">get cookie</a>
  <a id="set" href="#">set cookie</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Tried in localhost using FireFox 10.0.

Comment: lol I was typing the code from memory and C# muscle memory took over. I've corrected it.

Comment: Load in two tabs and try. You'll get two different values.

Answer (score 0):

Attempt number two =P

Try something like this:

```
<iframe id="cookies" src="refresher.html" style="display: none"; />
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        var ifr = document.getElementById('cookies');
        setInterval(function() {
            var cd = ifr.contentDocument.cookie.split(";");
                l = cd.length, i, k, ret = {};
            for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
                k = cd[i].split("=");
                k[0] = k[0].replace(/^ +| +$/g,'');
                k[1] = k[1].replace(/^ +| +$/g,'');
                ret[k[0]] = k[1];
            }
            window.cookiedata = ret;
        },5000);
    })();
</script>
```

refresher.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">setTimeout(function() {location.reload();},5000);</script>
```

You can still use jQuery `$.cookie` to **set** a cookie, but to **get** them you now use `cookiedata.cookiename`.

Adjust the `5000` to whatever seems a good compromise between responsiveness and reloading data.

Comment: Thanks. Please don't take this personally -- I know it's a product of browser "firewalling" -- but that just looks horrible ;)

Comment: It's probably because I refuse to use jQuery, ever, that you find this ugly :p Personally I find jQuery ugly, but to each his own I guess?